# CSS input type text and type select beahvior

Tags: css

I set the same width (100%) for input type=text and type=select.
Why if I put them side by side the input field type=text appears bigger than input type=select ?
How can I solve this strange behavior?

```
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="cell">
   <label>Year</label>
   <select name="modello">
       <option></option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <label>Year</label>
   <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tbl">
  <div class="cell">
   <label>Year</label>
   <select name="modello">
       <option></option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <label>Year</label>
   <select name="modello">
       <option></option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tbl">
  <div class="cell">
   <label>Year</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <label>Year</label>
   <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tbl {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

select {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h5ephew0/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't set the width of parent element(td). You can set the width at 50%:

```css
.tbl {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;/*set the width to 50%*/
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
select {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="cell">
    <label>Year</label>
    <select name="modello">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tbl">
  <div class="cell">
    <label>Year</label>
    <select name="modello">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <label>Year</label>
    <select name="modello">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tbl">
  <div class="cell">
    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if I do not want to set the size (50%) of the cell? U can get the same behavior of the input select and text in any other way? I could also have 3/4/5 cells. Thanks

Comment: You can just set a width like `width: 1px` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/h5ephew0/4/)